# Flot: Horizontal Stacked Bar - Remove Unnecessary Padding

Tags: jquery, flot

**jQuery**: 1.10.1
**Flot**: 0.7, 0.8
**JSFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/26gbkyb9/4/

For some reason, I can't seem to get rid of the padding (white space inside the grid, but outside the bars) on a horizontal bar. If you look at the JSFiddle link above, you can see that the problem doesn't exist on a vertical bar, so I can only assume it is a bug. However, I'm wondering if anyone has a fix that I can apply. I've dug through the [Flot Reference on GitHub](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md) without any luck whatsoever. *EDIT*: I should note that the padding only increases as the height of the graph increases.

Image of output:
[image: Image of output]

Code:

```
<script>
var datahorz = [
    {label: 'Compliant', data: [[90,1]]},
    {label: 'Noncompliant', data: [[10,1]]},
];          
var ticks = [[0, "0%"], [10, "10%"], [20, "20%"], [30, "30%"], [40, "40%"], [50, "50%"], [60, "60%"], [70, "70%"], [80, "80%"], [90, "90%"], [100, "100%"]]
var optionshorz = {
    series: {stack: 1,
             lines: {show: false, steps: false },
             bars: {show: true, align: 'center'},},
    bars: {horizontal: true, lineWidth: 0},
    yaxis: {show: false},
    xaxis: {ticks: ticks, tickSize: 100},
    legend: {show: false}, 
    grid: {borderWidth: 1}
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    $.plot($("#flot-placeholder30DayHorz"), datahorz, optionshorz);
});
</script>
<div id="flot-placeholder30DayHorz" style="width:600px;height:100px;margin:20px;"></div>
```

Any suggested workarounds are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plot automatically changes the min and max values for the y-axis on the horizontal chart to `0.48 ... 1.52` instead of `0.5 ... 1.5` (I have no idea why).

If you specify the min and max values in your `optionshorz` like this

```
yaxis: {
    show: false,
    min: 0.5,
    max: 1.5
},
```

you get the chart without padding. See the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/26gbkyb9/5/).

Btw: The same is true with the padding at the top of the vertical chart. Here the max value is set to `102` instead of `100`.

Comment: Thank you! I'm glad I asked  here, because I never would have considered that.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than setting the min/max values explicitly, you can also set the axis `autoscaleMargin` option to `null` to prevent the extra padding from being applied:

```
yaxis: {
    /* other options */
    autoscaleMargin: null
},
```

This will allow the chart min/max values to still scale automatically with the dataset, but without the added whitespace.